# How to properly work with Date Null in Xamarin.Forms-Azure-IOS

Tags: core-data, xamarin.forms, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I use Xamarin.Form with MicrosoftAzureMobileClient 4.02 and MrosoftAzureMobileClient.SQLiteStore.
My backend is in c# and I use Offline Sync.
All is working good except when I try to update one table to AzureDB.

In azureSQLDb the fields are set to Datetime2(0) and is nullable. But in the c# backend and in the Xamarin app I use DateTime.
All working good for the sync, and read, but if I try to update, I can see local CoreData table being fill with date like -62135578800 then when the sync with Azure start I receive this error: "The 'DateTest' property on 'Appel' could not be set to a 'null' value. Weird because the DB allows null on that field.

Do you think I need to use Nullable in backend and Xamarin App?

Why MicrosoftAzureMobileClient transform a null Datetime in -62135578800 in local coredata db?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your information:

After several tests. I think we must use Datetime? In the backend AND in the Xamarin.Forms.

I change all my code to support Nullable Date and the error is gone.